# How to restore files after a bad command in git

Tags: git, github, restore

Here is my problem. I was creating a new repository from a locally existing project. I wrongly added to many files to my commit, and when I wanted to remove these files from my commit I deleted all my local files.

All the files deleted are still in one commit:

[image: Check the commit here]

I would like to restore these files locally, but I can't push them, I think that to many large files were added.

[image: Check the push here]

How can I restore them locally since I can't push them and then pull them?

Keep in mind that these files were never push on the remote repository. They are also deleted from my local project. They are just still present in a commit. And when I try to push this commit I receive the error:

`fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly`

Answer (score -1):

You can use one of command from below

```
git reflog OR git reset OR git checkout
```